# Remove stop words in text file without NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 files: `stopwords.txt` and `a.txt`
I want to remove the stop words from file `stopwords.txt` in file `a.txt` and separated by white spaces.

How do I do it? This is what I've tried to do:

```
def remove_stopwords(review_words):
with open('stopwords.txt') as stopfile:
    stopwords = stopfile.read()
    list = stopwords.split()
    print(list)
    with open('a.txt') as workfile:
        read_data = workfile.read()
        data = read_data.split()
        print(data)
        for word1 in list:
            for word2 in data:
                if word1 == word2:
                    return data.remove(list)
                    print(remove_Stopwords)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [removing stop words without using nltk corpus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593068/removing-stop-words-without-using-nltk-corpus)

Comment: Welcome. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is expected of you to at least show what you have already tried yourself

Comment: Hi, I looked at that link and tried using solutions from it. However, I have only 2 files and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
k = []
z = []
with open('stopWords.txt', 'r') as f:
   for word in f:
        word = word.split('\n')
        k.append(word[0])

with open('a.txt', 'r') as f_obj:
    for u in f_obj:
        u = u.split('\n')
        z.append(u[0])

p = [t for t in z if t not in k]
print(p)
```

Iterate through each word in the stop word file and attach it to a list, then iterate through each word in the other file. Perform a list comprehension and remove each word that appears in the stop word list.

Answer (score 0):

`a.txt`:

```
good great bad
```

`stopwords.txt`:

```
good bad
```

Maybe:

```
with open('a.txt','r') as f, open('stopwords.txt','r') as f2:
   a=f.read().split();b=f2.read().split()
   print(' '.join(i for i in a if i.lower() not in (x.lower() for x in b)))
```

Comment: just a general thing (and not really the answer on your question, but at least a remark you'd might want to include) when you plan on removing stopwords without using a framework like NLTK there are a few things you'd need to consider.

1) Consider stemming. i.e. you'd want to remove plurals so that if 'dog' is considered a stopword, then dogs should be removed too. There are several ways to do this... ==> Delete all the s at the end of a word, or duplicate your stopwords and add an s to each, or use the len()method to see if a part is an exact match starting from 0.

Comment: @Clueless_captain Ok a lot of stuff, edit my answer, if you want, i'll approve

Comment: A second thing you might want to consider (and this is best done before stemming). Is to remove all capitalization; in Python ´ "Hello" == "hello" ´ would return ´False´, so it's not considered the same. Another thing you can try is to remove all short words.

Comment: @Clueless_captain Edited mine